# How do I dump only the data for all tables using mysqldump

Tags: mysql, mysqldump

I have a new database with schema and primary key, FK, index constraints created for all tables. How do I dump only the data from an existing database using mysqldump, so that I can import only the values alone and exclude everything else.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
mysqldump --no-create-db --no-create-info  ...options...
```

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html

Answer (score -3):

Use this in putty.........

```
mysqldump -u username -p'password' $db_name > $db_backup.sql
```